# Should we get rid of the tag [sex-perverts]?

Tags: discussion, tagging

The tag [sex-perverts](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex-perverts) has recently been created. Should we get rid of it?

From a purely classification point of view, it’s hard to agree upon what is or is not perverted. On a more serious note, the term may be used by some to lump in gay, lesbian, bisexual, polyamorous people and possibly others with people who engage in sexual abuse.

I think the term [sexuality](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexuality), which is used for all sexual behaviour, not just people’s sexual orientation, and [sexual-abuse](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexual-abuse) should be sufficient.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I agree. I edited it out of the question. I believe it will be automatically cleaned up, eventually, if it isn't used.